# MVC 4 "The using block is missing a } character"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, session

I'm trying to setup a shopping cart for my project.
I am storing the item name, price, and description into Session and call it back and eventually use it for payment processing.
I've written everything and am now having this weird error where it says
"} expected" in the error list.
Also, when I hover over @using in @using (Html.BeginForm("ValidateForm", "PayPal")),
it says "The using block is missing a } character".
I just don't know what the problem is.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "ShoppingCart";
}

<h2>ShoppingCart</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("ValidateCommand", "PayPal"))
{
var cart = Session["Cart"];
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-9">
        <h2><strong>Courses</strong></h2><br />

        @foreach (var item in cart)
        {
            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6 col-s-8 col-lg-4">
            <img src="~/Images/party.gif" style="width: 175px" class="img-responsive" />
            <h2>@item.className</h2>
            <input type="text" name="product" value="@item.className" hidden="hidden" />
            <input type="text" name="totalPrice" value="@item.classPrice" hidden="hidden"  />
            <input type="text" name="custom" value="@item.ClassID" hidden="hidden" />
        }
        <br />
        </div>

    </div>
    <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" name="btnConfirm" value="Check Out with Paypal" />

</div>
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your div and /div tags appear to be mis-matched, Razor views care about that sort of thing, make sure you open and close them inside the same code block (defined by curly braces)

Comment: wow, yes you are right. Thank you so much. That was driving me insane.

Comment: [Andrew Nurse on the razor parser](http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/Going+Deep/Andrew-Nurse-Inside-Razor/) 

Here is a good video about how the razor engine parses syntax.

Answer (score 4):

You have a "dangling-div". Here:

```
}
<br />
</div>
```

That `</div>` should be inside the `foreach` brace.